# AWS S3 PutLifecycleConfigurationAsync throws AmazonS3Exception

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lifecycle, aws-sdk-net

I'm using the AWS C# SDK. After getting the Lifecycle configuration of a bucket using the `GetLifecycleConfigurationAsync(bucketName)` method, I'm trying to save this configuartion (**even without any change**):

```
var result = await _client.PutLifecycleConfigurationAsync(new PutLifecycleConfigurationRequest()
            {
                BucketName = bucketName,
                Configuration = bucketLCConfiguration
            });
```

This throws AmazonS3Exception:

> The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rules created manually in the AWS console with scope of "Entire bucket" can contain configuration which include `Filter = null`.
This will cause an exception when trying to save this configuration.
One way to "fix" it is before saving set the null filter to empty one:

```
rule.Filter = new LifecycleFilter
            {
                LifecycleFilterPredicate = new LifecyclePrefixPredicate
                {
                    Prefix = string.Empty
                }
            };
```